# Why do the following expressions make no sense?

Tags: vectors

I have an exercise that says:

If $u, v$ and $w$ are vectors in $R^n, n\geq 2$, and $c$ is a scalar explain why the following expressions make no sense:

$A: u \cdot(v\cdot w)$

$B: c\cdot(u+w)$

So in $A$, $v\cdot w$ equals a number that is multiplied by $u$ that is a vector, so that should be a scalar multiple.
In $B$, $u+w $ equals a vector multiplied by $c$ that is a scalar should make another scalar multiple.

What am I assuming wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, $d=v\cdot w$ is a scalar, so you cannot use it in another dot product. In other words, operator $\cdot$ needs both elements to be vectors in the same dimension; but $d\in\mathbb{R}$, while $u\in\mathbb{R}^n$ (with $n\ge2$).

The second case is analogous: $u+w$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $c\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

You can't take the dot product of a vector with a scalar. In the first, $u$ is a vector and $v\cdot w$ is a scalar. In the second, $u+w$ is a vector and $c$ is a scalar. The dot product is only defined for vectors.